# CGContextSetShadowWithColor: shadow is flipped in UIView

Tags: uiview, cgcontext, shadow, flip

I am developing an iPhone application in which I want set the shadow for the path that I am drawing on UIView's context.

Following is the code snippet:

```
CGSize shadowSize = CGSizeMake(-4, -4);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(drawContext, shadowSize, blurRadius,
shadowColor.CGColor);            
//Stroke the bezier path
```

Since I am drawing an UIImage in the same context of UIView, I need to flip the context. All the drawing is fine except that shadow is shown in the bottom and right-side (my expectation was top and right sides).

When I tried this drawing in a context that I created (not the UIView context and hence not flipped), the shadow is appeared properly.

What is the problem here? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple docs ([Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)):

"Flipping the CTM to align an object with the default coordinate system of UIKit does not affect the object’s shadow, and so a shadow does not correctly track its object. To get it to track correctly, you must modify the offset values appropriately for the current coordinate system."